# Not able to run Mongodb on ubuntu

Tags: database, mongodb, installation

While trying to access the mongodb I am getting error that connection is failed

1. while running `mongod` command I am getting

   ```
   2019-02-25T11:05:05.870+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB 
   starting : pid=2580 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=gten
   2019-02-25T11:05:05.870+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version 
   v3.6.3
   2019-02-25T11:05:05.870+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git 
   version: 9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5
   2019-02-25T11:05:05.870+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL 
   version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
   2019-02-25T11:05:05.870+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: 
   tcmalloc
   2019-02-25T11:05:05.870+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: 
   none
   2019-02-25T11:05:05.870+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build 
   environment:
   2019-02-25T11:05:05.871+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     
   distarch: x86_64
   2019-02-25T11:05:05.871+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     
   target_arch: x86_64
   2019-02-25T11:05:05.871+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: 
   {}
   2019-02-25T11:05:05.962+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception 
   in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock 
   file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
   2019-02-25T11:05:05.962+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now 
   exiting
   2019-02-25T11:05:05.962+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting 
   down with code:100
   ```

and while I run `mongo` command, I am getting

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-02-25T11:16:44.802+0530 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I dont know what's the issue I have follwe the [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/] and [https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16.04/]
to install the mongo.

Config:
I am using UBUNTU 18.04.
Any help is appreciated i have gone through many answers and tried all but still facing the same issue.Thanks in advance

After doing a lot of stuff I am getting

```
2019-02-25T18:52:27.197+0530 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-02-25T18:52:27.200+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=27390 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=gten
2019-02-25T18:52:27.200+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.6
2019-02-25T18:52:27.200+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: caa42a1f75a56c7643d0b68d3880444375ec42e3
2019-02-25T18:52:27.200+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
2019-02-25T18:52:27.200+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-02-25T18:52:27.200+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-02-25T18:52:27.200+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-02-25T18:52:27.200+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2019-02-25T18:52:27.200+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-02-25T18:52:27.200+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-02-25T18:52:27.200+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-02-25T18:52:27.200+0530 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use
2019-02-25T18:52:27.200+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-02-25T18:52:27.200+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

Comment: It seems you may not have permission on the data/db folder.  You might want to take ownership for the account running mongo.

Comment: I think you dont have permissions . Please update the permissions

Comment: I have given the permissions but still not able to run

Comment: After setting permissions what error you are getting? Show us those logs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the error, message the user trying to start the mongod process don't have write access to /data/db folder.

Run the following command to enable the user to write to /data/db folder

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /data/db
```

or create a new folder with current users permission and start mongod with --dbpath option

```
mkdir mydata/db

mongod --dbpath mydata/db
```

Comment: yes i solved it by my own but your answer helps in some way

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: I have installed two snippets of mongo and one was already running and there were some other issues also like you said of permissions and also the lock file was giving the error. I just tried and come to a solution even I don't remember :)

Answer (score 5):

If you face this issue It means you are trying to connect mongo shall without 
running server on local which give this problem

[image]

Some system are not run mongo service automatically on start of machine.
So you need to start it manually.

Run this command to run service on every time when you start your machine or whenever you want to use mongo

```
sudo service mongod start
// or 
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Run `sudo service mongod status` and see what it returns. 
If it is stopped, 
  run `sudo service mongod start` to start the mongodb and try connecting to it.

If `sudo service mongod start` is giving a error then

Create the file `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If you still persist error please share console error. On start, we may help you better.

Comment: @AdeshKumar  Please try this updated solution and if problem persists share console error. or personal suggestion reinstall mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This may help.

```
sudo chmod 777 /data/db
```